# java.lang.IllegalAccessException-->module java.base does not open java.lang to unnamed module @1af2d44a

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception

*i am get the exception when run the program how to solve this java.lang.IllegalAccessException-->module java.base does not open java.lang to unnamed module @1af2d44a*

## exception is

```
type Application Execution Started..!!!
Dec 21, 2023 6:53:46 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.3.Final}
Dec 21, 2023 6:53:46 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Dec 21, 2023 6:53:46 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 21, 2023 6:53:46 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Dec 21, 2023 6:53:46 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
Dec 21, 2023 6:53:46 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect <init>
WARN: HHH000063: The Oracle9Dialect dialect has been deprecated; use either Oracle9iDialect or Oracle10gDialect instead
Dec 21, 2023 6:53:46 AM org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect <init>
WARN: HHH000064: The OracleDialect dialect has been deprecated; use Oracle8iDialect instead
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException-->module java.base does not open java.lang to unnamed module @1af2d44a
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:550)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319)
    at org.springframework.cglib.reflect.FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.helper(MethodProxy.java:135)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.init(MethodProxy.java:76)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:216)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:685)
    at com.jsp.dao.StudentDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a469befc.toString(<generated>)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4216)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:1047)
    at com.jsp.Main.App.main(App.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module java.base does not open java.lang to unnamed module @1af2d44a
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(MethodHandles.java:259)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:546)
    ... 18 more
here
```

i want the run the main program  get the result of the program with out exception

Comment: In 99% of all cases the answer is, when you update the Java version, you must update the frameworks and 3rd party libraries too.